# Issue with JuiceUI slider control after postback

Tags: asp.net, slider, controls, postback, juice-ui

I am using the DynamicControlsPlaceholder by Denis Bauer to save the viewstate of dynamic controls after postback. 
I used DynamicControlsPlaceholder before in an earlier part of my project and it worked flawlessly.

However, today I have run into difficulty. I have created a page where there are a number of text labels, slider bars and textboxes (defined by how many elements there are on a database) as shown below. The slider bars are JuiceUI slider controls and the text boxes are normal ASP.NET textboxes.

[image: Before PostBack]

After postback the text labels (literal controls) and pie chart disappear, the textboxes reduce in size (text inside remains) and the sliderbars are reset to the lowest value without the ability to move the slider (the sliders cannot move at all).

[image: After PostBack]

I am quite new to ASP.NET and I am completely stumped as to why this is happening. Do you think it is a problem with the dynamic control placeholder, JuiceUI slider or my code (see below)?

```
{

                SqlCeCommand cmdb = new SqlCeCommand();
                cmdb.CommandText = "SELECT CriteriaName,CriteriaDesc FROM tblCriteria WHERE (DecisionID = @DID)";
                cmdb.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DID", DID.Text.Trim());

                cmdb.Connection = sqlConnection1;
                reader = cmdb.ExecuteReader();

                string[] criterianames = new string[critno];
                string[] criteriadescs = new string[critno];

                int i = 0;

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    criterianames[i] = reader["CriteriaName"].ToString().Trim();
                    criteriadescs[i] = reader["CriteriaDesc"].ToString().Trim();
                    i++;
                }
                reader.Close();

                Cont2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<h3>Thank you for contributing to the following decision.<h4>Decision Goal: " + dgoal + "</h4><br><br><center>"));

                Series weights = new Series();
                weights.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;

                double[] yBar = new double[critno];
                string[] xBar = new string[critno];

                xBar = criterianames;
                for (i = 0; i < critno; i++)
                {
                    yBar[i] = 1;
                }

                ChartArea ca = new ChartArea();

                ca.Position = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 100);
                ca.InnerPlotPosition = new ElementPosition(0, 0, 100, 100);
                ca.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;

                Chart piechart = new Chart();
                piechart.RenderType = RenderType.ImageTag;
                piechart.ChartAreas.Add(ca);
                piechart.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                piechart.Palette= ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
                piechart.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                piechart.BorderSkin.PageColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
                piechart.BorderSkin.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;

                piechart.Width = 800;
                piechart.Series.Add(weights);
                piechart.ImageStorageMode = ImageStorageMode.UseImageLocation;
                piechart.ImageLocation = "~/TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)";

                piechart.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xBar, yBar);

                piechart.DataBind();
                Cont2.Controls.Add(piechart);


                Cont2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</center><h3>Please provide a weighting for each criterion.</h3><p>Please provide a weighting for each criterion along with a description of why you made this choice. </p>"));

                for (i = 0; i < critno; i++)
                {
                    Cont3.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<h3>" + criterianames[i] + "</h3><p><strong>Description: </strong>" + criteriadescs[i] + "</p><center>"));

                    Juice.Slider weightslider = new Juice.Slider();
                    weightslider.ID = "w" + i.ToString();
                    weightslider.Min = 1;
                    weightslider.Value = 50;
                    weightslider.Max = 100;
                    weightslider.AutoPostBack = true;
                    Cont3.Controls.Add(weightslider);
                    weightslider.ValueChanged += (o, a) =>
                    {
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + weightslider.Value.ToString() + "');", true);
                    };

                    TextBox wdesc = new TextBox();
                    wdesc.ID = "wd" + Convert.ToString(i);
                    wdesc.Rows = 3;
                    wdesc.Width = 900;
                    wdesc.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                    Cont3.Controls.Add(wdesc);
                    Cont3.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</center>"));

                }
                Cont3.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p align='right'>"));
                Button continue1 = new Button();
                continue1.Text = "Continue";
                Cont3.Controls.Add(continue1);
                Cont3.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</p>"));


                // Database Disconnect
                sqlConnection1.Close();
            }
```

Many thanks for any help you can provide,
Kind regards,
Richard

Answer (score 0):

You could eliminate or confirm the problem exists with Juice UI by creating a page containing nothing more than a Juice UI slider, one of these dynamic placeholders and a label. That'd be the first stop.

If you do run into problems with Juice UI, you can use it's cousin [Brew](http://shellscape.org/#brew)